# Overriding bootstrap styling on a list item <li> not behaving as expected

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm not a web tier person, so I apologize if this is a foolish question.

I'm trying to add an underscore boostrap pulldown menu item on hover and am getting an error indicating that I have an invalid property value.  I've gone through a bunch of gyrations, but current code looks like this.

**HTML:**

```
<li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle header-link"
                    data-toggle="dropdown">Clubs <span class="caret"></span></a>
```

And in the css file:

```
a.header-link {

    a.hover {
      text-decoration:underline;
    }
}
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

I thought showing ALL of the HTML might help, so...

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Rugby Clubs</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/styles.css">
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script
    src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script
    src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <!-- Logo -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">RUGBY</a>
            </div>

            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#mainNavBar">
               <span class="icon-bar"></span>
               <span class="icon-bar"></span>
               <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="mainNavBar">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle header-link"
                    data-toggle="dropdown">Clubs <span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Womens Rugby</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Mens Rugby</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">High School Girls Rugby</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">High School Boys Rugby</a></li>
                    </ul></li>
                <li><a href="#">Events</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
              <li><a href="#">Sign In</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Join</a></li>
            </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
a.header-link:hover {
      text-decoration:underline;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using a CSS Pre-processor like SASS or LESS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming by nesting you are using LESS or SCSS. In that case do this:

```
a.header-link {

    &:hover {
       text-decoration:underline;
    }
}
```

What you wrote would compile as is there was an anchor tag child to the .header-link that contained a class "hover". And you don't have that in the HTML. You have an icon instead ;)

If you are not using LESS or SCSS, then do not nest. That is only something you can do in the processors I mentioned. Do this instead:

```
 a.header-link {  something }

 a.header-link:hover {
    text-decoration:underline !important;
 }
```

Comment: I'm not using a preprocessor

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I'm still learning and haven't moved on to preprocessors yet.  I had attempted what you suggested, but no luck.  If I bring it up in firefox with the developer tools that style element doesn't show up.  In both chrome and firefox I still don't get the underline.

Comment: Try !important at the end. You may have other CSS specificities overwriting it. I edited my answer

Comment: it is bad practice to use the !important rule in **most cases**, sure you can use it, but for future use you need to make sure that you understand why it is written and have a good explanation for using it. otherwise the programmer that comes after you to read the CSS code will probably not understand why it is there and will use another specificity rules to overwrite it (such as writing rules inside tags etc.).

Comment: You are right, I normally wouldn't advice the !important rule. Haven't in months. But in this case, the specificity didn't work. And if you think explaining the !important rule to the next programmer is hard, try explaining a 3, 4 or more levels specificity. If it was my site, I'd find the specificity and correct it. I can't see his whole site, so I wouldn't be able to know

Answer (score 2):

#### Try This:

```
.header-link{
  text-decoration:none;
}
.header-link:hover{
  text-decoration:underline;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It should be like this:

```
a.header-link:hover {
  text-decoration:underline;
}
```

Comment: That's one of the iterations I tried.  In firefox developer that makes that css element disappear completely.  In both Chrome and Firefox I still don't get an underline.

Comment: Can you please provide a demo?

Comment: I put everything in the post now.  That's the entirety of what I'm running.  Thanks